# FileReader onload property containing a function that returns another function

Tags: javascript

I'm following a tutorial on using JavaScript to allow the user of a webpage to drag, drop and view an image all client side.

In the tutorial, a new FileReader object is created and the onload property defined:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.classList.add("obj");
img.file = file;
preview.appendChild(img); // Assuming that "preview" is the div output where the content will be displayed.

var reader = new FileReader();
//confusing line below:
reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

I noticed the onload property of reader is set to both a function and an object like this:

```
object.property = (someFunction)(someObject);
```

I don't understand this syntax. Is someObject passed to someFunction when the onload event fires? I also don't understand why the function returns another function, and what happens when it does?

[Relevant section of tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images)

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
```

In the above code, it is an IIFE with one parameter `aImg` and in the function body, it returns another function in which the `src` of `aImg` is set to `e.target.result` and `e` is the `event` triggered with the image upload and `e.target.result` is the image and it is assigned to `onload` event.

Now the `(img)` in the last. It is the `img` tag created previously and it is passed as an argument to execute the function.

Comment: So when this line is executed, rather than assigning the outer function as the `onload` method, the outer function is executed and returns the inner function as a object, which then becomes the `onload` method.

Comment: Two things I don't understand:
1. How does the interpreter know to immediately invoke the outer function, rather than using it as the `onload` method, but also knows to return the inner function as an object?
2. When `onload` fires and the inner function is invoked, why is `aImg` still defined as though it were in the context of the outer function? Before the inner function is returned as an object, the interpreter must be evaluating `aImg.src = e.target.result;` and realising that `aImg` is a reference to the `img` tag.  So what is actually happening?

Comment: I've just read up on IIFEs [here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), so I think I can answer question 1 myself. The parentheses after the outer function cause it to be immediately invoked. The outer function also need to be in brackets, otherwise the parentheses would interpreted as a separate statement.